# Raspberry Pi, ROS, Romeo board, Arduino - How are they interlinked? what are basic connections between them to build a robot?

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, ros, arduino-ide

I am a newbiee in building robots, And through searching internet i find out that we need Raspbery pi (a computer), Romeo board (The hardware), Arduino (Development environment), ROS (Robot operating system).

But i just don't understand how are these all used, What are their individual usage. Why each of these are used for?
Can anyone explain it to me?

What should I do, From where should i start?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

This might be better suited to the Robotics forum... however, I'd recommend starting with Arduino. Very beginner-friendly, very easy to find sample code and cheap projects to start with. Also, there are many books for Arduino development that explain all the hardware compatible with it.

Also, these things aren't required for all projects. I'm not entirely sure of your sources, but cool things can be done with Arduino alone, as well as along with these other tools.

Comment: I have seen some robotics forums but they explain these individually,
I want to know, how they work together?
When we have to use all this, From where to start, What all this component will be used to implement and all....